# How do I convert the nonce into an integer value with the official JS lib?

Tags: iri-legacy-api, javascript

I tried to use `fromTrytes()` but the function does not accept trytes with an odd length. The nonce appears to always have an odd length, e.g. `EPV9MUTXNFDAFNIQLAZWTOLAFJT`.

Answer (score 1):

`fromTrytes` is used to revert the `toTrytes` function (which encodes ASCII text into trytes, but will not support all encoded values).

You can use `Converter.trits` to convert your trytes into trits, then `Converter.value` to convert into an integer value. This works well for tags of milestones or for bundle index fields, but I am not sure whether a nonce is too long for that to fit into a JavaScript number without losing precision.